# JPA:find() vs query

Tags: jpa, jpql, entitymanager

I call find method on EntityManager two times for same value of identifier.So first call fires SELECT statement, but second doesn't as entity is already there in persistent context.And this is expected behaviour.
But if instead of second call to find(), I use JPQL to get very same entity, it fires another SELECT statement.
Though it returns same memory instance, but is issuing of SELECT not a wrong behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is NOT a "wrong behaviour". A query can return multiple objects. A JPA implementation is not there to check "does this JPQL mean the same as a `find` and the developer of this app was just being silly?". A query will issue a SELECT always. If a row of the results equates to an object in the L1 cache then that object is returned to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How is equality checked, by identifier or field-by-field comparison?If identifier is used then it may happen that stale entity is returned to the user,even though query has fetched latest one.

Comment: by id! that's what an id is for! It returns an entity in the L1 cache. If that has been updated elsewhere then the user is responsible for calling refresh(). But then this is in the JPA spec

Comment: Yes you are right.Thanks for inputs. After first call to find, I changed the row in DB manually.When JPQL query is executed, it does issue SELECT but still same instance is returned.